# Bootstrap 4 alert has unwanted bottom padding when not in container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a nice fixed bootstrap 4 alert.

My problem is that the alert has unwanted bottom padding when it is not placed inside a container. Since this is fixed and is being auto-centered I do not want it inside a container.

Heres my CSS:

```
  #alert {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
```

JSfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/81vhy56o/

How to fix?

Comment: it's coming from the `padding` on the `button`

Comment: Why is it doubling the alert height due to the button padding??

Comment: have you tried to add in #alert padding-bottom :0 ?

Comment: @kjdion84 Do you want to make alert div to stick in the footer without any spacing ?

Comment: Nope, I just want the alert to have its normal height. In the JSFIDDLE you can see the height of the alert is doubled for whatever reason.

Comment: Adding `padding-bottom: 0` only slightly corrects the issue, not completely.

Comment: try changing the line-height

Comment: The `Hi! I'm a test alert!` text is not aligned properly, it's not centered.

Answer (score 9):

If you inspect the element you can see that there is a `margin` on it not `padding`. To fix it just add the class `mb-0` to the `<div class="alert"></div>` which will make `margin-bottom: 0 !important;` and if you don't want any padding then you can add `pb-0` to it as well.

```css
#alert {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
  <head>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="alert" class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible mb-0 pb-0">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
      Hi! I'm a test alert!
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
```

Comment: Adding class `mb-0` to the alert div fixed this for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

add your own class named `.alert-dismissible .close` class and add
 `padding-bottom:0` to it

```
.alert-dismissible .close{
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

and in `#alert` id add `padding-bottom:0`

```
#alert {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't know why you were not upvoted but this solution works best for me.